# Describe the elements of $\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Describe the elements of $\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Isn't this field the splitting field of $f(x)=x-\pi$ over $\Bbb Q$? If so then I think I have that $\Bbb Q(\pi) \cong \Bbb Q[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$. How can I figure out what kind of elements are there in $\Bbb Q(\pi)$? Gallian's book states that the elements in $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ should be of the form $c_{n-1}a^{n-1}+c_{n-2}a^{n-2}+ \dots + c_1a+c_0$ for $c_i \in \Bbb Q$. Now since $x-\pi$ is of degree $1$ I would only have the term $c_0 \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: No, this is not the splitting field.  Look for the definition.

Comment: Note that $x-\pi$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q[x]$, so your quotient doesn't make sense.

Comment: The phrase "splitting field of $x-\pi$ over $\Bbb Q$" implies $x-\pi$ is an element of $\Bbb Q[x]$, which implies $\pi$ is an element of $\Bbb Q$, which is wrong. You are right that the splitting field of any linear polynomial would just be the base field, though. Note $\pi$ is not algebraic, it's transcendental, so it is not the root of any polynomial. When $T$ is transcendental over a field $F$, we know the elements of $F(T)$ are all rational expressions in $T$ with coefficients from $F$.

Comment: Note that $\pi$ is transcendental (well-known but not trivial to prove) so $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ is *not* an algebraic extension.

Comment: I think there should be a way to describe the elements without knowing that $\pi$ is transcendental. The problem is from Gallian's algebra book and the word "transcendental" is used the first time after the chapter in which the problem is proposed.

Comment: @SleepWalker Can you at least use that $\pi$ is not the zero of any polynomial with rational coefficients?

Comment: I would think so. Gallian just states that the answer for this should be that the elements are of form $(a_n\pi^n+ \dots +a_0)/(b_m\pi^m+ \dots +b_0)$ but I don't know how to come up with this.

Comment: All fields are closed under the arithmetic operations. Thus, if $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ contains $\pi$, it must contain powers of $\pi$, their linear combinations, and ratios thereof. That is, it contains all rational expressions in $\pi$. And the set of all such expressions is closed under the operations, so it is itself a field. Because any field containing $\Bbb Q$ and $\pi$ contains the field of rational expressions in $\pi$, it is the *smallest* field containing $\Bbb Q$ and $\pi$, i.e. it is $\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Comment: The fact $\pi$ is transcendental is not needed for any of what I said. It is necessary, however, to go further and say the only simplifications (of the fractions) that occur are the ones guaranteed by elementary algebra (as opposed to any special properties of $\pi$), namely factoring and cancelling factors.